# SQL Fiddle - ORACLE 11G and Stored procedure

Tags: oracle, sqlfiddle

I wanted to ask about another problem and another one came out;)

I wanted to use SQL Fiddle for example, but it doesn't work for me to create a table and a procedure that generates random data...

Why this example not work (build schema not work)?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6915f/2

```
create table tab (
     id_tab integer not null,
     val1 integer,
     val2 integer,
     val3 integer,
     val4 integer,
     val5 integer,
     val6 integer,
     val7 integer,
     val8 integer,
     val9 integer,
     CONSTRAINT tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_tab)
  );
  
  create index val1_index on tab (val1);
  create index val2_index on tab (val2);
  create index val3_index on tab (val3);
  create index val4_index on tab (val4);
  create index val5_index on tab (val5);
  create index val6_index on tab (val6);
  create index val7_index on tab (val7);
  create index val8_index on tab (val8);
  create index val9_index on tab (val9);
  
  create procedure test1 as
  begin
    for x in 1..1000
    loop
      insert into tab(id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
      values ((select nvl(max(id_tab), 0) + 1 from tab), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9),
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9), 
              dbms_random.value(1,9));
    end loop;
  end;
```

result:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: I edited your [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6915f/4)

Comment: [DB<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e0b12e92be1cfa303a538ce4de14fe11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure has to be ended with a slash; so you need to add that, and change the build-schema command separator from the default `;` to `/` - and then change all of the other separators in your code from semicolons to slashes:

```
create table tab (
     id_tab integer not null,
     val1 integer,
     val2 integer,
     val3 integer,
     val4 integer,
     val5 integer,
     val6 integer,
     val7 integer,
     val8 integer,
     val9 integer,
     CONSTRAINT tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_tab)
)
/
  
create index val1_index on tab (val1)
/
create index val2_index on tab (val2)
/
create index val3_index on tab (val3)
/
create index val4_index on tab (val4)
/
create index val5_index on tab (val5)
/
create index val6_index on tab (val6)
/
create index val7_index on tab (val7)
/
create index val8_index on tab (val8)
/  
create index val9_index on tab (val9)
/
  
create procedure test1 as
begin
  for x in 1..1000
  loop
    insert into tab(id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
    values ((select nvl(max(id_tab), 0) + 1 from tab), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9),
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9), 
            dbms_random.value(1,9));
  end loop;
end;
/
```

As you need an anonymous block to call the procedure, you need to do the same thing - including changing the default separator - in the other section too:

```
begin
  test1;
end;
/

select * from tab
/
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a87fd3/1)